# WPF ProgressBar controltemplate how to bind Template Background

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controltemplate, valueconverter

Simply put I have a progress bar that acts as a battery indicator.

I want to do a very minor template override.

The background of the battery should change based on a range of battery levels.

The actual progress bar is bound to an integer value in my viewmodel called BatteryLevel.

This is then passed into a Converter to return a Background.

The problem is...the binding in the ControlTemplate isn't changing the background color of the Border.

It effectively stays blank (maybe null...not sure).

**My question:  What is necessary to be able to accomplish binding the PART_Indicator to the ProgressBar's Background**

Here is my code to override the template.

```
<ProgressBar Name="_batterystat" Background="{Binding BatteryLevel, Converter={StaticResource BatteryLevelToColorConverter}}">
    <ProgressBar.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="PART_Track" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="PART_Indicator" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ProgressBar.Template>
</ProgressBar>
```

and the converter:

```
public class BatteryLevelToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var battLevel = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

            if (battLevel <= GlobalsService.BatterLevelCriticalSetting)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            if (battLevel <= GlobalsService.BatterLevelLowSetting)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just tried a simple demo, the template works fine. If you set some other Brush value for the `ProgressBar`'s Background, you'll see it works. So it's just the problem of binding the `Background` (to `BatteryLevel`). You should double check that.

Comment: King King - Thanks.  You were absolutely right.  Like an idiot I was never binding the VALUE property.  Obviously I'm not going to see the background change if I never set the Value.

Ugh...your comment helped me to see that.  Do you want to add this as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: no thanks, I think it's too simple for an answer, it's just kind of some trifle mistake (simple as a typo:)

Comment: fair enough.  Thanks again.